# Java - Assigning User Input to Variable / Change Counter

Tags: java, user-input

I'm quite new to java, although I have a fairly basic knowledge of C++.
For my assignment I am counting change and sorting it into American currency (i.e., if you had 105 cents, it would divide it into one dollar and one dime).
Logically I understand how to do this, but I'm having some serious trouble understanding the java syntax.  I'm having serious trouble to find a way to assign a user-inputted value to a variable of my creation.  In C++ you would simply use cin, but Java seems to be a lot more complicated in this regard.

Here is my code so far:

```
package coinCounter;
import KeyboardPackage.Keyboard;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class  helloworld
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        Scanner input new Scanner(System.in);
        //entire value of money, to be split into dollars, quarters, etc.
        int money = input.nextInt();
        int dollars = 0, quarters = 0, dimes = 0, nickels = 0;

        //asks for the amount of money
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of money in cents.");


        //checking for dollars, and leaving the change
        if(money >= 100)
        {
            dollars = money / 100;
            money = money % 100;
        }

        //taking the remainder, and sorting it into dimes, nickels, and pennies
        else if(money > 0)
        {
            quarters = money / 25;
            money = money % 25;
            dimes = money / 10;
            money = money % 10;
            nickels = money / 5;
            money = money % 5;
        }

        //result
        System.out.println("Dollars: " + dollars + ", Quarters: " + quarters + ", Dimes: " + dimes + ", Nickels: " + nickels + ", Pennies: " + money);

    }

}
```

I would really appreciate some help with how to assign a user-input to my variable, Money.  However, if you see another error in the code, feel free to point it out.

I know this is really basic stuff, so I appreciate all of your cooperation.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line :

```
Scanner input new Scanner(System.in);
```

To :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

And this should be after line below not before:

```
System.out.println("Enter the amount of money in cents.");
```

And as you did , the line below will read from input `int` value and assign it to your variable money :

```
int money = input.nextInt();
```